# svn list does not show new files after svn add and svn commit

Tags: svn

I have a local svn repository running. Works fine.

Then I created a new folder inside my working copy `./modules/newFolder`. The folder `./modules` (and all it's old contents) where under revision already. `newFolder` obviously not.

I went ahead and ran `svn add /modules/newFolder/` and `svn ci`. There was the output like

```
A    modules/newFolder/subFolder…
… and so forth
```

And I thought all is well. To be sure I checked with `svn list modules/` and was surprised to find out `newFolder` **missing** from `modules/`.

Where is it? What did I do wrong? I'll update this post with all the information you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, svn unfortunately does not refresh the state from the server after a commit. Have you done an `svn update` recently?

When working with svn, it's a good idea to always make an `svn up` right after a commit.

Comment: That's it. Simple `svn up` did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

May be it will take some time to reflect your commit changes on server.

Comment: It's local and it has been days.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the folder `./modules/newFolder`. Then run `svn update && svn ci`. After that recreate the folder `./modules/newFolder`. Finally, run `svn update && svn ci`. Folder should be added then...